# How can I add a Title of the webApp build with Google Appscript

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I have a project wherein I have created a file named javascript.html, page.html , stylesheet.html and code.gs . I want to print out the title of my web app. Passing the title in page.html in `<head>` tag. However the same is not working. Is there any other way to do the same in Google appscript.

Below you can see there are three html tags. However I have defined only one in my page.html in appscript code.

[image]

Below is the code : [image]

Other than that I haven't added any html tag in my code.
Kindly let me know how to do so?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your Web Apps with `doGet()` function, how about using `setTitle`? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("sample title");
}
```

- By `setTitle("sample title")`, when the source of Web Apps is seen, you can see `<title>sample title</title>` in the HTML header.

#### Reference:

- [setTitle(title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setTitle(String))

Comment: Thankyou Your solution always works!! :) Can I set faviocon icon using the same method?

Comment: @kanu priya Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, how about [setFaviconUrl(iconUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setfaviconurliconurl)?

Comment: Thankyou @tanaike